# My HP Laptop has "DDR4-2666 / PC4-21300 DDR4 SDRAM SO-DIMM" (4GB) in one slot, Can I put "DDR4-2400 SODIMM" ( 8 GB ) in the other slot?

Tags: laptop, memory, memory-limit, hp-laptop

I have HP Laptop 15-bs1xx ? It has Intel Core i5-8250U Processor on HP 832A Motherboard.

It has two memory slots. In one, as per HWinfo tool, I have "DDR4-2666 / PC4-21300 DDR4 SDRAM SO-DIMM" 4GB.

I want to expand my memory.

I saw a cheap 8GB memory ( Crucial 8GB DDR4-2400 SODIMM CT8G4SFS824A ) online. It is "DDR4-2400 SODIMM". Would this be compatible with my HP laptop ?

[Screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzulT.jpg)

[Scrrenshot 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuVGD.jpg)

Please Help !  I don't want to end up with the wrong RAM.

Update: I purchased "ADATA 2666 Mhz 8 GB DDR4" RAM, as I got some negetive comments regarding pairing with 2400 Mhz. Another advantage with ADATA was it had same clock speed, latency and timing. Now, It is working fine and fast as Dual Channel 12GB RAM :). Had to shell few more bucks though !

Comment: Have you considered doing the work by checking the documentation, checking with Crucial, or something else indicating you've tried to find the answer on your own?

Answer (score 1):

**Probably** it will work, but both stick have to work at the same speed. So the faster one needs to slow down. It's best to get two sticks with the same parameters.